# Miktek not compiling

Tags: compiling

I had successfully been compiling a 20 page document, then things went bad for some reason
I'm copying the compiler output which I hope will help someone.  Also noticed there is no .gz file or log file in the directory of the source code.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/lin-ryan/polarchapterlast.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\epsfig.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"))))
No file polarchapterlast.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))) [1{C:/Users/St
eve/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (polarchapterlast.aux) 
)<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
Output written on polarchapterlast.pdf (1 page, 11307 bytes).
SyncTeX written on polarchapterlast.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on polarchapterlast.log.
```

---

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/lin-ryan/polarchapterlast.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\epsfig.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"))))
(polarchapterlast.aux)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))) [1{C:/Users/St
eve/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (polarchapterlast.aux) 
)<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
Output written on polarchapterlast.pdf (1 page, 11307 bytes).
SyncTeX written on polarchapterlast.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on polarchapterlast.log.
```

---

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

Comment: don't use texify if you get errors. Its error messages are quite useless. Run pdflatex and bibtex or whatever tool you want to use.

Comment: also `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>` ??? You have not updated miktex for 5 years?